# Magento guest checkout/authorize.net issue

Tags: magento, checkout, authorize.net

I am trying to determine how to debug an issue in Magento version 1.3.1:

When a customer uses guest checkout, the Authorize.net payment option is not available.

However, if the user revisits his cart and resumes guest checkout the Authorize.net option does appear.

We have now found that if Authorize.net is set to "all allowed countries" instead of "specific countries", then Authorize.net is available at guest checkout

We have not been able to upgrade Magento without breaking the integration into the parent site.

Thank you -- Tony

Comment: Any chance you've got a dev environment where you can test an upgrade to 1.5.x?

Comment: Feel free to add your findings as an answer, in case others have the same issue :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with 1.6.0. Everything was working fine with the saved CC during testing, but when I shut that off and turn Authorize.net on, it ost the ability. So this is what I did to fix it.

I initialized the CC (Saved) back on, at the same time saved the config, checked it and sure enough, it came back on. So I then disabled the saved option again and then everything worked. My guess is when I turn off saved and initializedAuthorize an the same time, the settings were incorrectly written. Anyhow, worth a try if someone runs across the same problem .